# change siblings background on mouse over

Tags: css

I have an `ul` with 3 li-s:

```
<ul>
    <li area="london"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I want to do the next thing (with CSS):

when the mouse overs the li with the attribute area, I want to change the backgrounds of all of his siblings.

if the mouse overs that doesn't have an attribute of area, change only his background.

```
li {
    background:rgb(237, 237, 255);
}

li[area] {
    background:rgb(237, 237, 255);
}
```

Comment: Area isn't a valid attribute. You may want to use data attributes instead (`data-area="london"`).

Comment: Unless your "area" element precedes all of its siblings, what you're asking for is not possible.  Sounds like this might be a structuring problem, though.  If the non-"area" elements are directly related to the "area" element, they should be descendants, not siblings (and then what you're asking for *will* be possible).

Comment: Why is this working..since it seems to in the answer's JSfiddle if `[area]` is not a CSS attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried few things and I think I got the solution. Since you wanted this to happen with CSS only, here's the [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8XAb/) link where you can see it in action.

```
li, 
li[area]:hover  {
background:rgb(237, 237, 255);
}

li:hover,
li[area]:hover + li,
li[area]:hover + li + li {
background: rgb(237, 237, 230);
}
```